# XSL match multiple variables with XML

Tags: variables, xslt

I'm trying to match xsl variables i.e. key1, key2 with xml node strings.
Problem: the xsl variables can vary like key1, key2, key3, key4, until key.length...
Question: How can I modify my xsl so when the key[i] is used, then ti will display all the xml node matches.

Here's my XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
<metadata>
  <field>marketing business</field>
  <field>PageTitle1 One</field>
  <field>marketing business link</field>
  <field>planning development</field>
  <field>PageTitle2 Two</field>
  <field>planning development link</field>
  <field>learning development</field>
  <field>PageTitle3 Threee</field>
  <field>learning development link</field>
</metadata>
</document>
```

Here's my XSL:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:variable name="key1">marketing</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="key2">business</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:for-each select="document/metadata/field">

<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains(.,$key1) and contains(.,$key2)">
      match <xsl:value-of select="." /><br/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="contains(.,$key2)">
      match <xsl:value-of select="." /><br/>
    </xsl:when>
    <!--... add other options here-->
    <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

Result:

```
match marketing business
match marketing business link
```

Any help? or is there a way to put this in an array-like variable or any different approach?...

Answer (score 1):

Consider putting your "keys" in a separate XML document, call it "keys.xml"

```
<keys>
    <key>marketing</key>
    <key>business</key>
</keys>
```

Then, you can create a single variable in your XSLT to reference this document

```
<xsl:variable name="keys" select="document('keys.xml')/keys" />
```

With this variable you can then, for example, check if your **field** element matches all the keys like so:

```
  <xsl:variable name="matches" select="count($keys/key[contains(current(), .)])" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$matches = count($keys/key)">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:variable name="keys" select="document('keys.xml')/keys" />
  <xsl:variable name="totalkeys" select="count($keys/key)" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="document/metadata/field">
      <xsl:variable name="matches" select="count($keys/key[contains(current(), .)])" />
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$matches = $totalkeys">
          matches all <xsl:value-of select="." /><br/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$matches = 1">
          matches one <xsl:value-of select="." /><br/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$matches > 0">
          matches some <xsl:value-of select="." /><br/>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```